# Android Firebase Listview ---> Hashmap Fail

Tags: android, listview, layout, hashmap, firebase

I am trying to retrieve the Restaurant Name data from Firebase and output them in individual lines on ListView. I created a sample of the data which only consists of numbers(strings).

Retrieving the data seems fine as I could output them line by line in console, but my Hashmap is saving everything into the same "node" or "field"

Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot Snapshot) {
            int x = 1;
            //Do some stuff once
            for (DataSnapshot RestNames : Snapshot.getChildren()) {
                name = RestNames.getValue().toString();
                //System.out.println(name);
                map.put(x, name);
                x=x+1;
            }
            System.out.println(map);
            Items.add(map);
            System.out.println(Items);
            listView.setAdapter(mgadapter);
        }
```

The Output in the console is as follows :

```
 {8=3456, 11=9, 9=34567, 5=3, 3=3, 4=4, 10=0, 1=1, 7=345, 6=34, 2=2}
```

Android emulator shows the same value for every single row.

I want to display each value on a separate row.

Thank you!

EDIT: SNIPPET OF JSON

```
{
 "Eat": {
  "Name": {
   "-Jy3yehAkgqhg4knlxx_": "1",
   "-Jy3yjQT2AxtZMqD2kov": "2",
   "-Jy3yk96Mo5MKOEEzviJ": "3",
   "-Jy3yksamL08R0BckxNZ": "4",
   "-Jy5JBJYZUTxZQtmdDmi": "3",
   "-Jy5JIXT_lDZrUOkF3T1": "34",
   "-Jy5JJ0oMqGrs2vfFge2": "345",
   "-Jy5JJTyET830PYOT3yA": "3456",
   "-Jy5JJu-jDGMDXncWDKf": "34567",
   "-Jy5JVejdsUtggM8vBoi": "0",
   "-Jy5JbwEoWrKAi6XIVQY": "9"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a snippet of your JSON into the question? You can get this easily from your Firebase data dashboard by executing this in the Chrome JavaScript console: `new Firebase('https://mine.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) { console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val(), null, '  ')); }, function(e) { console.error(e); })`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please see my snippet at the bottom of the post, thank you!

Comment: This isn't directly relevant to the question, but I highly recommend naming your variables `snapshot` and `restNames` instead, so it's clear that they are objects rather than classes. It would at least make the syntax highlighter work right. :)

Comment: @fluffy thanks :D I will do so after

Comment: Firebase also has an OS lib to help with populating ListView: https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're missing some code in your snippet, I completed it an ran it locally:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/32367022/Eat/Name");
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        int x = 1;
        Map<Integer,Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        for (DataSnapshot child: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = child.getValue().toString();
            System.out.println(name);
            map.put(x, name);
            x=x+1;
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

This prints out the following for me:

```
1
2
3
4
3
34
345
3456
34567
0
9
{1=1, 2=2, 3=3, 4=4, 5=3, 6=34, 7=345, 8=3456, 9=34567, 10=0, 11=9}
```

The first lines show the output from inside the `for` loop. The last lines shows the `HashMap`.

I use the most basic of Java classes, and this behavior seems correct to me.

I expect that the `System.out.println(name);` inside the `for` loop will display the same output as above for you, because the Firebase SDK handles ordering there.

If the order in the loop is correct, either your `map` or your `Items` object changes the order. It is impossible to say without seeing the types of these.

But in general, the approach above is how you should troubleshoot this problem: isolate it to a single object/class and then either fix what's wrong with that class (if it's your code) or replace it with a class that works for your use-case (if it comes from a library).

Update: I created a minimal app that shows the numbers in the correct order in a list view in [this Github repo](https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android).

[image: App running in an emulator]

Comment: Thanks for the help , I did exactly like your code but the *Map* order is still incorrect and I have searched other posts, they just add the entire Map onto ArrayList object to add to the ListView adapter, but mine just simply outputs {8=3456, 11=9, 9=34567, 5=3, 3=3, 4=4, 10=0, 1=1, 7=345, 6=34, 2=2} for 11 times on ListView.

Comment: That means you're listening to the wrong level of the tree. Your ref is probably pointing to `Eat` instead of `Name`.

Comment: My original path is /Eat/Name , but they all returned the same set of results.  I just tried changing hashmap to linkedhashmap and it returned the list in order. But I am still having trouble with the listview displaying entire set for 11 times. Thanks a lot for the help though

Comment: Minimal app showing how to display the numbers in an Android Listview: https://github.com/puf/firebase-stackoverflow-android

Comment: ^The above really helped me to solve the problem, I realized I didn't know how to store the items using String array, but this really helped! Thanks so much Frank!